# MapBox marker don't return first click

Tags: android, mapbox

I handle onMarker click after `onMapReady` by the code below but it don't return callback at first click. However, it return callback when click at marker normally from second click.

```
mapboxMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new MapboxMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(@NonNull Marker marker) {
        Log.i("TAG", "MARKER clicked");
        return true;
    }
});
```

Full demo source code of `MainActivity` is [HERE](https://pastebin.com/UB6QJVLn)

I am using mapbox `5.0.2`. How can I receive first click at marker?

**UPDATE**
If I use `getMarkerViewManager().setOnMarkerViewClickListener` the `onMarkerClick` always called 2 time at first time I click on `MarkerView`, after that it never call when I click on `MarkerView`

```
mMapBox.getMarkerViewManager().setOnMarkerViewClickListener(new MapboxMap.OnMarkerViewClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(@NonNull Marker marker, @NonNull View view,
            @NonNull MapboxMap.MarkerViewAdapter markerViewAdapter) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you do before? Add Markers or add Listener?

Comment: @RamilGabdrakhmanov I add marker. I also add full demo source code to my question. Hope you can check it

Answer (score 1):

I think you also add this code:

```
mapboxMap.getMarkerViewManager().setOnMarkerClickListener(new MapboxMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(@NonNull Marker marker, @NonNull View view, @NonNull MapboxMap.MarkerViewAdapter adapter) {
        Log.i("TAG", "MARKER clicked");
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: I am new to MapBox. Can you explain more. what is the `clusterManager`? Thank you

Comment: @PhanVanLinh I had edited the answer，You also find more in this [link](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/8236)

Comment: Thank you for your helpful link. but the solution doesn't work well. the `onMarkerClick` for every click but it return twice

Comment: Try my new onMarkerClick callback

Comment: Your code is incorrect now. if you try it in AndroidStudio, it will display syntax error. you need to use `getMarkerViewManager().setOnMarkerViewClickListener`. I already try this and got the error that I have tell to you in the above comment

Answer (score 0):

I find 1 trick for solve my problem that is every time I add `Marker` to map I also select `Marker` by use `selectMarker`

```
MarkerView markerView = mapboxMap.addMarker(markerViewOptions);
mapboxMap.selectMarker(markerView);
```

It will make marker return click listener at first click. However I think it is not a good solution